# Ruby tracking self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, self

Let's say I have a controller:

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController
  def index
    MyModel.new.some_method(self)
  end
end
```

I would expect **self** be an instance of *HelloController* here, but since it's being passed as an argument to an instance of `MyModel.new.some_method`, I'm wondering if it might be an instance of *MyModel* instead.

So what is the value of **self** in my example?

Comment: you model will receive a reference to the HelloController, to an instance of HelloController to be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of self in your example is an instance of HelloController

you can easily see that for yourself if you bundle 'pry' into your application and then stick a binding.pry in the def index() method